# What font will be used for PDFs if Helvetica font unavailable

Tags: pdf, fonts

If a PDF is created using Helvetica as a font but that font is not available on an end users machine is there any way to determine what font will be used in its place? The file is generated with the font and appears correct on an Ubuntu 16.04 and correct on windows when viewed in chrome. However when viewed in adobe reader some of the letters are overlapping each other.

Couple of notes, the file in question is generated in the Polish language and being viewed on computers setup with an American locale and language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Adobe website](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-fonts.html):

> When a font cannot be embedded because of the font vendor’s settings, and someone who opens or prints a PDF does not have access to the original font, a Multiple Master typeface is temporarily substituted: AdobeSerifMM for a missing serif font, and AdobeSansMM for a missing sans serif font.

If you want to be sure the document looks and prints as expected, embed the fonts you used when creating it.

Comment: Thank you for the information, it appears that the font is not being embedded and that will need to be fixed in order to resolve this issue.